# File not found exception once deployed to Server

Tags: asp.net, image, sharepoint, file-upload, filenotfoundexception

I am using the below code to Upload an Image file to a SharePoint Document Library. The code works fine locally but once deployed to server, i get the Exception as file not found.

```
                String fileToUpload = FlUpldImage.PostedFile.FileName; //@"C:\Users\admin.RSS\Desktop\Photos\me_skype.jpg";
                String documentLibraryName = "SiteAssets";
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);

                SPFolder myLibrary = web.Folders[documentLibraryName];

                // Prepare to upload
                Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
                String fileName = CheckStringNull(txtFirstName.Text) + CheckStringNull(txtLastName.Text) + CheckDateNull(txtDOB) + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload); ;
                if (fileName.Contains('/'))
                {
                    fileName = fileName.Replace("/", "");
                }
                if (fileName.Contains(':'))
                {
                    fileName = fileName.Replace(":", "");
                }
                FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);
                //Upload document
                SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);
                string url = site.ToString() + "/" + spfile.ToString();
                if (url.Contains("="))
                {
                    url = url.Split('=')[1];
                }
                //Commit
                myLibrary.Update();
```

The string fileupload contains URL as **`C:\Users\admin.RSS\Desktop\Photos\me.jpg`** This URL is actually the client system and the server side code throws exception as file not found. How to handle this issue?

**UPDATE:**

I removed the lines of code that checks if the file exists and now i get the exeption on `FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);` as `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\20120605_133145.jpg cold not be found`

Kindly help. Thank You

Comment: I think **C:\Users\admin.RSS\Desktop\Photos\me.jpg** is an address on remote machine and could be not checked by `System.IO.File.Exists` method.

Comment: @Mazdak_SH Yes it is an address on remote machine, How to handle the same?

Comment: would you try Server.MapPath() method?

Comment: @Mazdak_SH Do u mean to say Server.MapPath(fileToUpload);?

Comment: Do u want to check if the file exists, then proceed to upload?

Comment: @Mazdak_SH  Not really required.

Comment: so, what does the if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload); do?

Comment: @Mazdak_SH it does check if file exists, Do u think i should proceed upload without checking file exsts condition?

Comment: No, of course i dont. But I think this method does not work in remote machine.I suggest that you check if the file exists on the server, where your user uploads files, some where like ~/Images/Upload/ and based on FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName, check if file is or not exists.However, replaceExistingFiles is always true, Whereas it seems that its value must be related to if(!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload)) condition :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15112/discussion-between-ishan-and-mazdak-sh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the file physically onto server and than working on the same helped me resolve my issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
        if (this.fuAvatarUpload.HasFile && this.fuAvatarUpload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
            string mimetype;
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".png":
                case ".jpg":
                case ".gif":
                    mimetype = file.ContentType;
                    break;

                default:
                    _model.ShowMessage("We only accept .png, .jpg, and .gif!");
                    return;
            }

            if (file.ContentLength / 1000 < 1000)
            {
                Image image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
                Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(image, 150, 150);
                byte[] byteArr = new byte[file.InputStream.Length];
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    resized.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    byteArr = stream.ToArray();
                }
                file.InputStream.Read(byteArr, 0, byteArr.Length);
                profile.ImageUrl = byteArr;
                profile.UseGravatar = false;
                profileService.UpdateProfile(profile);
                this._model.ShowApprovePanel();
            }
            else
            {
                _model.ShowMessage("The file you uploaded is larger than the 1mb limit.  Please reduce the size of your file and try again.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's better if you can give an explanation of exactly what changes you are suggesting - otherwise we have to try and figure it out ourselves. SO is not just about fixing problems, but understanding why the fix works for next time