# Error when uploading file to SP - could not find file: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\

Tags: sharepoint-2010, filestream

I'm uploading a file to a SharePoint Document library using the following code:

```
string fileToUpload = oFile.PostedFile.FileName;

using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(spsite))
{
   using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
   {
       SPList library = oWeb.Lists[documentLibraryName];
       using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open))
       {
         //more logic here
```

This works fine in my dev environment, but when I move it to QA, I get the following error when try to upload a file:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\file_to_upload'.
```

I have googled around, and it seems like I may need to use PostedFile.InputStream instead of PostedFile.Name.

But if set fileToUpload equal to oFile.PostedFile.InputStream, then I am not able to use this bit of code anymore:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open))
```

I would like to still use this code as I need to access fs.name later on in my code.

Any idea how I could get this problem resolved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877829/file-not-found-exception-once-deployed-to-server

Comment: Have seen that question...there is not a useful answer on it.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try, this might be helpful

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/96f81cea-12b2-46f0-83ec-64c7fd9532cd/using-aspnet-fileupload-control-in-sharepoint-2010-announcement-list-newformaspx?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious